# How to get number of delimiters in line 1 and adding the number of delimiters to the end of the line and then saving as a new file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, delimiter

I want to count all the “,” in a line (row) 1 in a file and then compare it to each line thereafter, if there are less “,” that in line one, add the difference “,” at the end of that line into a new file, by making use of Powershell.

How do I create a new file with the missing delimiters?

Any ideas and help will be appreciated.

Data File:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
1,2
```

New Data File Needed:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,,,,,
1,2,3,4,,,,,,
1,2,3,,,,,,,
1,2,,,,,,,,
```

Here is my script:

```
$file = 'C:\Test\File1.csv'    
$i = 1
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file)
$line = $reader.ReadLine()
$reader.Close()
$delimiter = $line.Split(",").Count
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file)
     try {
        for() {
            $line = $reader.ReadLine()
             if ($line -eq $null) { break }
         $c = $line.Split(",").Count
         if($c -ne $delimiter -and $i -ne ${lines})  {
            ($d = $delimiter - $c) 
            if($c -ne $delimiter) {
            $varline = $line + ",".PadRight($d, ",") 
            $line -replace $line, $varline

            
                
            Write-Host "Line number: $i"
            Write-Host "Delimiters in line: $c"
            Write-Host "Delimiters should be: $delimiter" 
            Write-Host "Difference: $d"
            Write-Host "New Line: $varline"
            } 
                 }
                 $i++
         } 
     } 
     finally {
        $reader.Close()
     }
Set-Content "C:\Test\TestMod.csv" -Value $varline
```

Write-Host Output: (*Only for testing purposes, not needed*)

```
1
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
Line number: 2
Delimiters in line: 9
Delimiters should be: 10
Difference: 1
New Line: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
2
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,,
Line number: 3
Delimiters in line: 8
Delimiters should be: 10
Difference: 2
New Line: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,,
3
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,,
Line number: 4
Delimiters in line: 7
Delimiters should be: 10
Difference: 3
New Line: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,,
4
1,2,3,4,5,6,,,,
Line number: 5
Delimiters in line: 6
Delimiters should be: 10
Difference: 4
New Line: 1,2,3,4,5,6,,,,
5
1,2,3,4,5,,,,,
Line number: 7
Delimiters in line: 5
Delimiters should be: 10
Difference: 5
New Line: 1,2,3,4,5,,,,,
6
1,2,3,4,,,,,,
Line number: 8
Delimiters in line: 4
Delimiters should be: 10
Difference: 6
New Line: 1,2,3,4,,,,,,
8
1,2,,,,,,,,
Line number: 10
Delimiters in line: 2
Delimiters should be: 10
Difference: 8
New Line: 1,2,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is; how to create a new file with missing delimiters?

Comment: What if a line in the middle of the file has more commas than the first line?

Comment: The first line should be the headers of the columns, if a line in the middle of the file has more commas, then the commas should be deleted.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: From PowerShell 7, you can simply use the [Import/Export-csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) cmdlets: `Import-Csv .\File.csv |Export-Csv .\TestMod.csv -UseQuotes Never`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an arbitrary processing pipeline for modifying each line in a text file and outputting the results to a new text file, like this:

```
Get-Content $outputPath |ForEach-Object { <# process file content here #> } |Set-Content $outputPath
```

Since the processing of every single line except for that first one consists of the same operations every time:

- Count number of `,`'s
- Calculate difference from number of `,`'s to the count from the first line
- Append trailling `,`'s

... all we need is two variables - one to keep track of whether we've inspected the first line, and one to hold the comma-count:

```
$inFile = 'C:\Test\File1.csv'
$outFile = 'C:\Test\output.csv'

$initialized = $false
$commaCount  = 0

Get-Content -LiteralPath $inFile |ForEach-Object {
  if(-not $initialized){
    # first line, let's just count the commas
    $commaCount = $_.Split(',').Length - 1
    $initialized = $true
  } else {
    # subsequent lines, calculate the difference in number of commas 
    $commaCountDiff = $commaCount - ($_.Split(',').Length - 1)
    if($commaCountDiff -gt 0){
      # and add missing ones 
      $_ = "${_}$(',' * $commaCountDiff)"
    }
  }

  # output the line (modified or not)
  $_
} |Set-Content -LiteralPath $outFile
```

Comment: @HeinvanRooyen Sorry that should've been `$commaCount - $_.Split(',').Length - 1`, not the other way around :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this by looping the data lines twice:

```
$data = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Test\File1.csv'
# first loop to get the maximum number of fields in the data
$maxFields = ($data | ForEach-Object {($_ -split ',').Count} | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
# second loop to output the lines with extra commas (empty fields) appended
$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_ + ',' * ($maxFields - ($_ -split ',').Count)
} | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Test\TestMod.csv'
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,,,,,
1,2,3,4,,,,,,
1,2,3,,,,,,,
1,2,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 0):

A big thanks to [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen)

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
$inFile = 'C:\Test\File1.csv'
$outFile = 'C:\Test\output.csv'

$initialized = $false
$commaCount  = 0

Get-Content -LiteralPath $inFile |ForEach-Object {
  if(-not $initialized){
    # first line, let's just count the commas
    $commaCount = $_.Split(',').Length - 1
    $initialized = $true
  } else {
    # subsequent lines, calculate the difference in number of commas 
    $commaCountDiff = $commaCount - $_.Split(',').Length +1
    if($commaCountDiff -gt 0){
      # and add missing ones 
      $_ = "${_}$(',' * $commaCountDiff)"
    }
  }

  # output the line (modified or not)
  $_
} |Set-Content -LiteralPath $outFile
```